# How can i find cross-correlation of time series data by using pandas library of python?

Tags: python, pandas, cross-correlation

I have annual daily timeseries data of rainfall and groundwater level and I want cross-correlation between these two variables. How can I do this in Pandas with lags of months? I want to check in which month GWL shows a high correlation with rainfall.

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible input (as DataFrame constructor) and the matching expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.